# Python pandas drop issue on a date header

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel document that has three rows ahead of the main header(name of columns).
[Excel document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OFfi.png)

When loading the data in pandas data frame using :

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel('output/tracker.xlsx')
print(df)
```

I get this data(which is fine):

---

```
 Date/Time:13/06/2022 Unnamed: 1   Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 
0                     NaN        NaN          NaN        NaN 
1                     NaN       2763         2763        NaN 
2                     NaN    Site ID  Company Site ID     Region 
3     203990318_700670803  203990318       689179   Nord-Ost
```

I do not need the first three rows so I run :

```
df = df.iloc[2:]
```

It removes the rows that have ID of 0 and 1.

But it doesn't remove the Date/Time:13/06/2022 Unnamed:  1 etc row.

How do I remove that top row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather directly load the data without the useless rows using the `skiprows` parameter of [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
df = pandas.read_excel('output/tracker.xlsx', skiprows=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I get this data(which is fine):

[`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) by default assumes 1st row is header, i.e. it does hold names for columns, which looking into snippet of your data is not case, use `header=None` to inform `pandas` that there are not names of column, but rather data, that is

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel('output/tracker.xlsx',header=None)
print(df)
```

then you should be able to remove these as you already did

Comment: If I use that I just get an extra header, so this won't work.

Skip rows until the row I need from the get go is the way to go. Thanks for the answer!